# Query to output customers and employees and their cities where each city must contain at least one customer and one employee

Tags: sql, sql-server

I must take sellers and customers and output them in one column, showing their cities and types.

My problem is: I don't need to output customers whose cities aren't in sellers' table and vice versa.

```
SELECT 
    ContactName, City, Type 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         'Seller' AS Type,
         ContactName, City
     FROM 
         [dbo].[Suppliers] t
     GROUP BY 
         City, ContactName
     UNION
     SELECT 
         'Customer',
         ContactName, City
     FROM 
         [dbo].[Customers] t
     GROUP BY 
         City, ContactName) t
GROUP BY 
    ContactName, City, Type
```

Result :

```
| Ivan Ivanov  | Seller   | Moscow |
| Piotr Petrov | Seller   | Moscow |
| Ivan Romanov | Customer | Moscow |
| Johnny Bravo | Customer | London |
```

(let's assume there are no sellers in London therefore this column shouldn't exist)

Expected result: only columns with information where a city has at least one seller and one customer grouped by contact name and city

Comment: *Customers and employees* or *Suppliers and customers* like your query? Clarify and post sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like `union all` and `exists`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.ContactName, 'Customer' as type, c.City
FROM Customers c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Sellers s WHERE s.city = c.city)
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT s.ContactName, 'Seller' as type, s.City
FROM Sellers s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Customers c WHERE c.city = s.city);
```

I'm not sure the `SELECT DISTINCT` is really needed -- I don't see why the underlying tables would have duplicates (although `ContactName` is not really a good column for unique identification).  However, your original query has `GROUP BY`, suggesting that you want to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: Distinct is not needed, there can be people with same names. I haven't mentioned they all have unique IDs assigned to them in their tables